Can't seem to find a way to have & in a term description show up as &
In a site on D9. I have a vocabulary that has titles as the term descriptions.
One of the term descriptions is This & That
No matter what I try, the & is converted to & in CKeditor4.
This happens as soon as it's typed. I.e., clicking Source shows the text as
<p>This &amp; That</p>

and the eventual rendering is the same.
I've tried all text formats for the CKEditor text, and have, in the Basic filter, turned off any plugins for fixing HTML, etc., No effect.
As to the suggestion of using the raw value. The field in the view is set to rewrite results as such:
{{ description__value__value }}
with description__value__value being defined in the list as the raw value.
The preview (and actual page using the block) show the result as:

This &amp; That


What is the problem with the behavior and what is your question?

Does this answer your question? How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?

No. I'm adding more information at the top. Using the raw value isn't working.

So this was a killer. CKEditor escapes the &. Then the field is provided by Views and renders in plain text escaped, rather than becoming unescaped when viewing it (so x &amp; y on the final page rather than x & y).
Most of the solutions given for the escaping of an ampersand assume that it is being done by twig. In this case, twig wasn't escaping the value because it was already escaped.
In the end, I needed to create a view field template specifically for this field (I could have been more generic, but the issue is just this field) to override the use of the default base theme view field template.
In that, this solved my issue:
{% set data = field.original_value %}
{{ data|replace({'&amp;': '&'})|striptags }}
The 'striptags' is because CKEditor also wraps the field value in paragraph tags when it escapes the & for some reason.

Ampersand is a special character, representing the start of an HTML entity.
CKEditor is correct to convert your plain-text ampersands into the valid entity equivalent of &amp;.
If it didn’t do this, your HTML would be invalid, and the browser may not be able to display the document correctly.
This isn’t something to fix, everything is how it should be.

I’d say that the title displaying as “This & That” on the rendered page is not correct. More importantly (to me), that is what the client thinks!

Does this help explain? https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612166/what-characters-must-be-escaped-in-html-5
